# XSLT transformation of comma seperated data returned from SQL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

**I return info from SQL using XSLT 1.0 like this:**

```
<xsl:if test="../Field[@Name='TheDBFieldName'][.!='']">
    <xsl:element namespace="http://BlahBlah" name="TheResult">
        <xsl:value-of select="../Field[@Name='TheDbFieldName']" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

**My Current result looks like this:**

1,2,3,6

**I need to return it like this:**

```
<TheDBFieldName>
    <TheResult>
        <Result>1</Result>
    </TheResult>
    <TheResult>
        <Result>2</Result>
    </TheResult>
    <TheResult>
        <Result>3</Result>
    </TheResult>
    <TheResult>
        <Result>6</Result>
    </TheResult>
</TheDBFieldName>
```

**Unfortunately XSLT 2.0 is not an option for me**

Any help on this including and example using my infowould be greatly appreciated!  I have been unable to apply current examples to mine example mainly because of my use of SQL data rather than absorbing an XML file

Comment: You can use the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions to split your raw result at the commas.  Create a named template to emit the `<TheResult>` elements recursively, by chewing up the input one item at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` in a recursive template call.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<Field Name="TheDBFieldName">1,2,3,6</Field>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Field">
    <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($input,',')"/>
    <TheResult>
      <Result>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($input,','),','))"/>
      </Result>
    </TheResult>
    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$remaining"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<TheDBFieldName>
   <TheResult>
      <Result>1</Result>
   </TheResult>
   <TheResult>
      <Result>2</Result>
   </TheResult>
   <TheResult>
      <Result>3</Result>
   </TheResult>
   <TheResult>
      <Result>6</Result>
   </TheResult>
</TheDBFieldName>
```

To adapt to your stylesheet, add the `tokenize` template and change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../Field[@Name='TheDbFieldName']" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
  <xsl:with-param name="input" select="../Field[@Name='TheDbFieldName']"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Daniel thank you for the reply.  This looks promising.  I tried this example in my code and got it implemented without error.  
However, when I run it, I get a White Space error.  

The error:
White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded.  Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead.

Any thoughts?

In the meantime I will continue to try to tweak this excellent example.

Comment: I am using .net XslCompiledTransform  -  Thanks for the info...I will try your suggestions right now and report back with the results.  - Thank you !

Comment: Your suggestion of removing the xsl:strip-space corrected the bug and it is working perfectly now.  Thank you for your help!!